# Google App Engine trying to access dev data

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm running my app on my local machine and using the remote API to access a datastore on my production side. Everything was working great until I tried adding a second app in google app engine launcher (I believe this is what caused the issue) because I had to merge what I was working on with some more up to date code and wanted to test as I went along. Suddenly I can't even access the remote datastore anymore. I get the error

```
app s~buybottandrew cannot access app dev~buybottandrew's data
```

I tried clearing the local datastore which allows me to access the remote datastore once, then the problem comes up again.

I read suggestions on the default_partition flag and I've tried passing that as well, with a muitiplicity of different things including nothing and an empty string.

```
--default_partition=s~buybottandrew
```

It gives me the same error no matter the argument

```
dev_appserver.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --default_partition=s~buybottandrew
```

If I remove all my remote api code and deploy it when I test it on the production server everything works perfectly. I can't seem to narrow down what is going on for the life of me.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`--default_partition` was removed in the new SDK. If you want to use the legacy SDK function, you can use `old_dev_appserver.py --default_partition`

Comment: Well that is good to know. They must have replaced the functionality with something?

Comment: @Andrew no idea. If you find out if they did that, please let me know. I could surely use the answer to that as well. Thanks! :)

Comment: I found a temporary fix. I was editing some config files though that I shouldn't be touching. `/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py` Line 84 I changed to `'s~%s'` instead of `'dev~%s'`. I also reported a bug. No one anywhere seemed to have a good idea why my application was trying to access two different data stores.