# Using remote data store on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to use the remote data store on Google App Engine on localhost, but I really can't get it to work.

I have tried following this advice [Remote_api configuration with App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413826/remote-api-configuration-with-app-engine) which does seem to handle the first request and uses the remote datastore (I think), but on the subsequent request it does not, and I get the error:

> "BadRequestError: app s~myapp cannot access app dev~myapp's data"

I have also tried the following:

- [BadRequestError: app s~myapphr cannot access app dev~myapphr's data. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280613/badrequesterror-app-smyapphr-cannot-access-app-devmyapphrs-data-why/9281772#9281772)
- [Google App Engine trying to access dev data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502414/google-app-engine-trying-to-access-dev-data)

and a lot of other suggestions, but without any luck.

Any ideas on how to use the remote datastore on localhost ?

thanks

Thomas

Comment: Just a question... by "remote datastore", do you mean you want your localhost's devserver to hit your app's datastore? Looking at your error, it does seem to be what you're doing. And this just won't work